# Does a SUB subscriber in ZeroMQ have any "callback"-mechanism as in ROS?

Tags: c++, zeromq, ros

I am a newbie in ZeroMQ.

I use [ROS](http://www.ros.org/) frequently. Hence I am confused by the subscriber in ZeroMQ. Most of the time in ROS, the subscriber is having a callback function, which is called automatically whenever data is available in the corresponding rostopic.

Please see below code snippet, borrowed from [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29):

```
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}
//define subscriber and callback function associated with it
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, chatterCallback);
```

However, in ZeroMQ, it seems that subscriber is kept in a loop to receive the data, as shown below:

```
for (int update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 100; update_nbr++)
{
    zmq::message_t update;
    int zipcode, temperature, relhumidity;
    // receive the data
    subscriber.recv(&update);
    // do something with data
    std::istringstream iss(static_cast<char*>(update.data()));
    iss >> zipcode >> temperature >> relhumidity;
}
```

The above code is borrowed from [ZeroMQ wiki](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:wuclient).

Does there exist any callback-mechanism, similar to ROS Subscriber, in ZeroMQ too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no callback system in ZMQ. You have to call `recv()` function in order to receive a message.

You can implement one using `recv()` since it blocks and returns a status, so you can use it in an `if` condition and a `while` loop.

I often use a pattern like this one with a timeout :

```
zmq::context_t zmq_context(1);
zmq::socket_t zmq_socket(zmq_context, ZMQ_SUB);

zmq_socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:58951");

std::string TOPIC = "";

zmq_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, TOPIC.c_str(), TOPIC.length()); // allow all messages
zmq_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_RCVTIMEO, 1000); // Timeout to get out of the while loop since recv is blocking
while(run) {
    zmq::message_t msg;
    int rc = zmq_socket.recv(&msg);  // Is blocking until you receive a message
    if(rc) { 
        // You received a message : your data is in msg
        // Do stuff here : call your function with the parameters received from zmq
    }
}
// Clean up your socket and context here
zmq_socket.setsockopt(ZMQ_LINGER, linger);
zmq_socket.close();
zmq_context.close();
```

Comment: I see. Is there any chance that `zmq_socket.recv(&msg)` receive same message again? It may be possible that `while` loop is too fast or something like that? I am not sure if it makes sense or not.

Comment: Assuming you are not sending  multipart message, if one message is sent, only one message will be received. The loop won't be too fast since it will block on the `recv` call until a message is received or you reach the timeout.

Comment: Yeah. One more question. Is there a way that a *publisher* can know if any *subscriber* is connected to it or not? Basically, what I am thinking is I can pause the *publisher* doing its job and only resume it when *subscriber* is connected.

Comment: A message sent to a topic that noone is listening will be dropped by a PUB socket. Otherwise, you can use XPUB to see the subscribe / unsubscribe message manually.

Comment: You mean that there is no harm in keep publishing messages because ZeroMQ is going to drop it if no subscriber is connected? Actually to build the message for publishing, I need to do a lot of calculations (functions call). I can skip it if I can know connected subscriber by using API.

Comment: From a networking point of view , yes there is no harm in publishing message that noone wants. If you want to manage a list of subscriber, you need to do it manually using XPUB socket

Comment: With all due respect, most distributed-systems programming **never allows a blocking** mode of any `.recv()` to ever happen, it is an awfully bad habit even for a school-book grade examples, as it is a resources devastating anti-pattern for any professionally meant software. Always expect not to wait a nanosecond on any attempt to receive using **`.recv( ..., ZMQ_DONTWAIT )`** and rather pre-`poll()` or just loop-through with a due ex-post return code handler.